# How to create and use a table in Power Apps with working Excel formulas in the cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I want to integrate in my Power Apps data from Excel and make it work in the similar way how in Excel, means to build a table and use in cells original formulas from Excel

-- What is the best way to do it?

-- Can I do it in Power Apps Canvas or I have to use Model-driven App and use Excel as a container for the table with formulas?

-- Can I import/migrate Excel file with data and formulas, or I need to insert the formulas in the code to the data after I migrate it?

Thank you in advance for any ideas and advices, I'm new in Power Apps, so the question may seem stupid

Comment: You can play with Excel Online connector to check what is possible in your case. https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/shared_excelonlinebusiness/excel-online-business/

Comment: Thank you! the most important that it's not integrated into Power Apps natively